# Jogl-2.0 doesn't support GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable.addKeyListener(this); ?

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, jogl

I'm using Jogl 2.0 , and when I try to do

```
public class Walking3D implements GLEventListener, KeyListener {

@Override
public void init (GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable) 

{


  // some code 

   gLDrawable.addKeyListener(this);

}}
```

I get : `The method addKeyListener(Walking3D) is undefined for the type GLAutoDrawable`

But in **Jogl 1.0** it works fine .

What's wrong with it ?

Thanks

Comment: http://download.java.net/media/jogl/jogl-2.x-docs/javax/media/opengl/GLAutoDrawable.html that method no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

Okay , I fixed it with this :

```
((Component) gLDrawable).addKeyListener(this);
```